# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5679: server supports 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using Macbook

Psycopg2 works well when connecting the localhost db (PostgreSQL on Mac). The error was raised when I tried to connect PostgreSQL db on a Windows10.

the following code is what I have for connection, the host is just the IP of the windows10

```
db= psycopg2.connect(database='dbname',user='username',password="secret",host="192.168.3.9",port="5432")
```

Errors:

```
  File "path/to/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5679: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
```

Is this because of system compatibility or something else? I've tried other Windows machine and I got no luck to make it work.
However, I was able to connect PostgreSQL on windows while I using  [Node.JS module pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`1234.5679` is the special code sent by the client to request SSL-encrypted database connections, and support for that has been in PostgreSQL since [commit e0e7daef6da](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/87h82kzwqn.fsf%40news-spur.riddles.org.uk) in 1999. But your PostgreSQL cannot be that old, because support for protocol version 3.0 was not added before 2003.

Actually, from studying `src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c` and reading the mailing list, this is a bug on the PostgreSQL server:

The client must be configured to try GSS authentication, and when the server rejects, it wants to negotiate an SSL connections, but the server doesn't expect that at this point; hence the error.

See the discussion [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/87h82kzwqn.fsf%40news-spur.riddles.org.uk). The bug has been fixed with release 12.3.

As a workaround, disable either GSS authentication or SSL negotiation on the client.

In psycopg2, disabling SSL is done by using `sslmode="disable"` in the connection string, and disabling GSS is done with `gssencmode="disable"`. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) for details.

Comment: Sorry for pointing my finger too rashly, it is a PostgreSQL server bug.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I had the same bug using docker's `12.1-alpine` image, the bug doesn't show up when using `12.1` image.

Comment: @cglacet That must be because you are doing something different. This is at the moment a live bug, and the proposed fix has not been applied to the code yet.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no, that's the exact same code for both tests, the only thing I changed is the `FROM` directive in my *docker-compose* file. In both cases I mount a volume `/var/lib/postgresql/data` to my local host. When I connect to the database from the host (also running version `12.1`) the error message shows when the database was created by the `12.1-alpine` docker container, but not when it has been created by the `12.1` container.

Comment: The source doesn't lie.

Comment: I had the exact same experience as @cglacet. Using the `12.1-alpine` image, I see the bug but using the `12.1` image, I don't see the bug.

Comment: I had the same using last Postgresql.app on mac since since a few days. Disabling SSL in the service helped my way out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how to find GSS Authentication and SSL in postgre? Are they in some kind of file that I need to edit? @LaurenzAlbe?

Comment: @Long_NgV I have added a description how to disable SSL and GSS in client connections. The database is called "Postgres", not "Postgre".

Answer (score 8):

Adding **?gssencmode=disable** to the connection string worked for me:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@localhost:5432/database_name?gssencmode=disable')
```

Answer (score 5):

Getting a similar error working with Laravel and Postgres. Solved it by putting this in my .env file: `PGGSSENCMODE=disable`

Comment: Whenever you answer questions, do not hesitate to clarify, what you proposed solution does, where you got the idea and what possible drawbacks might be.
Furthermore, to disable encryption, when the server clearly provides some support is not a good idea, even for local databases. Someday one might move the database to a different host, and not realize, that he just majorly messed up.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed this Psycopg2 module through conda command, then uninstall that module and install using pip command.

Command:
pip install Psycopg2

The above command may resolve your issue. I resolved through this step

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a SSL connection working and using certificates, you can disable GSS connection mode to avoid the client to attempt to connect with GSS and directly try a SSL connection (Postgres version 12 < 12.3, I had no such issues with a test on version 11).

Below an example with the verify-ca option, providing filenames for certificates and key (example names from GCP Cloud SQL, running Postgres 12.1 when posted).

```
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine

   db_user = 'user'
   db_pwd = 'secret'
   db_host = 'hostname'
   db_port = '5432'
   db_name = 'test'

   cnn = f'postgresql://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}'
   ssl_args = {
       'gssencmode': 'disable',
       'sslmode': 'verify-ca',
       'sslrootcert': 'server-ca.pem',
       'sslcert': 'client-cert.pem',
       'sslkey': 'client-key.pem',
   }
   
   engine = create_engine(cnn, connect_args=ssl_args)
```

This engine can then be used with pandas for example:

```
   df.to_sql('my_table', con=engine)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PostgresSQL 13.0 I had the same problem, displaying the error messages:

```
 unsupported frontend protocol 255.255: server supports 2.0
 unsupported frontend protocol 0.0: server supports 2.0 to
```

according to this site it [postgresql.org](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A2171014-AF39-4231-B162-B094302E1C65%40eggerapps.at) deals with the SSL / GSS Protocol Negotiation Problem. Which should already be resolved in Postgres version 12.0

I was able to solve it following the guidelines contained in these sites:
[highgo.ca](https://www.highgo.ca/2020/03/30/postgresql-gssapi-authentication-with-kerberos-part-3-the-status-of-authentication-encryption-and-user-principal/)

In the postgres terminal, I executed the command below setting the environment variable gssencmode = disable and the problem was solved:

```
  psql -h localhost -U postgres -d "dbname=belez gssencmode=disable";
```