# Empty OperationalError psycopg2.connect

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am creating a connection to a postgreSQL database from Python using psycopg2.connect. However I get an empty OperationalError. Does anyone have an idea on why it may be?. Next I put the output of the console.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "medicion",user = "postgres", password = "xxxxx", host ="localhost", port = "5433")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-906939287b4e>", line 1, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "medicion",user = "postgres", password = "xxxxx", host ="localhost", port = "5433")

  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

OperationalError
```

Comment: Do you able to connect to the server using `psql`?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I can connect to the server through the SQL Shell (psql). I am learning PostgreSQL and have established connections to this database using access, DBeaver and pdAdmin but I have not been able to do it in python using psycopg2.

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file (I don't know where is it in Windows, try to google).  If there are no any records about failed connections then something wrong with psycopg2 itself. PS https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/417

Comment: The PostgreSQL log shows the following: FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5679: server supports 2.0 to 3.0.  Here I found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190010/psycopg2-operationalerror-fatal-unsupported-frontend-protocol-1234-5679-serve. Thanks for the orientation.

Comment: Bless the spirits of the ancestors! Good to know that you solved the problem :)