# How do you use Rstudio to connect to a Google Cloud PostGress Database?

Tags: r, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, rstudio, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to use RStudio to connect to the a Google Cloud postgres database. My R code is below.
From the documentation I'm relatively sure I have the correct setup.

```
# Load the DBI library
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)

# Helper for getting new connection to Cloud SQL

getSqlConnection <- function(){
  con <- dbConnect(
    RPostgres::Postgres(), 
    dbname = 'my_dbname', 
    host ='my_host', 
    port = 5432, 
    user ='username', 
    password = 'my_password' )  
  return(con)
}

conn <- getSqlConnection()
res <- dbListTables(conn)
print(res)
```

When I run the code above I'm getting the error

`Error: FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5679: server supports 2.0 to 3.0`

I was hoping someone might have some advice on the error or how to setup a Rstudio connection to a Google Cloud postgres DB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `1234.5679` looks like a value to be replaced. Otherwise this looks like postgres localhost connection.

Comment: Your issue seems to be simillar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190010/psycopg2-operationalerror-fatal-unsupported-frontend-protocol-1234-5679-serve). Could you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62829485/8394595), addind the SSL args to your code and give it a try?